# Are order of keys() and values() in python dictionary guaranteed to be the same?

Tags: python, dictionary

Does native built-in python dict guarantee that the `keys()` and `values()` lists are ordered in the same way?

```
d = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3, 'D':4 } # or any other content
otherd = dict(zip(d.keys(), d.values()))
```

Do I always have `d == otherd` ?

Either it's true or false, I'm interested in any reference pointer on the subject.

PS: I understand the above property will not be true for every objects that behave like a dictionary, I just wonder for the built-in dict. When I test it looks as if it's true, and it's no surprise because having the same order for `keys()` and `values()` is probably the simplest implementation anyway. But I wonder if this behavior was explicitly defined or not.

Comment: In CPython 3.6 (and all other python implementations starting with 3.7), dictionary items stay in the order they were inserted in.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary's history of insertions and deletions. If `items()`, `keys()`, `values()`, `iteritems()`, `iterkeys()`, and `itervalues()` are called with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the lists will directly correspond.

From [the documentation for `dict`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesmapping.html).

Comment: so d and otherd will always be the same.

Answer (score 4):

Python 2.7 and above have [ordered dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-0372), for which your statement:

```
d == dict(zip(d.keys(), d.values()))
```

would apply

Comment: as it already applies for every dictionnary, it should certainly still be true for ordered dictionnaries