# Random order of dict keys on server vs local machine

Tags: python, dictionary

Explaining this could be hard. I have a very long and complicated script. The final product of this script is a nested dictionary (normal dict, not `OrderedDict`).

What I cannot explain is that when I run the script on a local machine, the dictionary has always the same structure (keys, values and nested keys and values). When I run the same script on a server I don't get any error, but the dictionary structure changes every time (randomly). Keys are always in a different position and so nested keys and values.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Can it be a different python version? On the local machine python3.6 and on the server 3.5

Comment: and potentially https://stackoverflow.com/q/30585108/1358308 as you're using older versions of Python

Comment: Yes, Python dictionaries before Python 3.7 are *inherently* unordered. In Python 3.6, insertion order was an implementation detail, and in 3.7+ it is part of the standard.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) (under `.values()`):

> Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

Comment: thanks! I was not aware of this!