# Inconsistent replication of numpy random generator using random.RandomState(None) or 0

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed

I have had this problem before. At the time, I imported random a number of times.
This time I import numpy a single time among all modules.

**EDITED**
Using `None` might have been the problem. But still not working with 0.
Minimal example working, so it's deeper in the code and not about importing anything (the example imports the same modules)...

**EDITED2**
I'm now guessing it has to do with **sort** in a list?

Not even: `PYTHONHASHSEED=0 python main.py` from [Disable hash randomization from within python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585108/disable-hash-randomization-from-within-python-program) worked

EDITED3: By the way, this is not a simple problem as the straight answer may suggest. It's actually a hard problem.

I use the code:

```
import numpy as np


class Model:
    def __init__(self, seed=0):
        self.np = np
        self.seed = self.np.random.RandomState(seed)
```

**Note** the `max_distance` is exactly the same. But the coefficient numbers are different.

[image: output]

And here (in another module, as I pass `self`) is how I calculate the gini coefficient:

```
def calculate_gini(incomes, model):
    # Sort smallest to largest
    cumm = model.np.sort(incomes)
    # Values cannot be 0
    cumm += .00001
    # Find cumulative totals
    n = cumm.shape[0]
    index = model.np.arange(1, n + 1)
    gini = ((model.np.sum((2 * index - n - 1) * cumm)) / (n * model.np.sum(cumm)))
    return gini
```

So. My question is: what are other possible sources of stochasticity that I'm not seing? And how can I control them?

All over the code I use random as such:

```
    def initialize_person(self):
        n = self.params['N_PEOPLE']
        ages = self.seed.randint(self.params['MIN_AGE'], self.params['MAX_AGE'], size=n)
        females = self.seed.choice([True, False], size=n)
        industries = self.seed.choice(list(self.industries.values()), p=[i.size for i in self.industries.values()],
                                      size=n)
        for i in range(n):
            skilled = self.seed.choice([True, False], p=[industries[i].p_skill, (1 - industries[i].p_skill)])
            income = self.seed.lognormal(industries[i].income_mean, industries[i].income_variance)
            person = Person(_id=str(i), age=ages[i], female=females[i], industry=industries[i],
                            skill=skilled, income=income)
            self.persons.append(person)
```

Details: This was produced in Linux Mint latest version 20.1 Ulyssa
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 15:48:22)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux

Comment: @user:163633 can you help?

Comment: why the hassle of passing `np` to `model.np`?

Comment: where did you use the Model class? I only see lower case 'model'

Comment: Just trying to make sure there was a single reference to numpy... @qu

Comment: I pass self to the function that is in the other model @b

Answer (score 0):

Seed must not be None.

Correct is:

```
def main(params, seed=0):
    my_model = Model(params, seed)
    my_model.run()
    my_model.logger.info('All done...')
```

Incorrect is:

```
def main(params, seed=None):
    my_model = Model(params, seed)
    my_model.run()
    my_model.logger.info('All done...')
```

Even thought the model was:

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self, params, seed=0):
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to store the numpy module as an attribute, just import it in any module that needs it; There are no "multiple instances" of the numpy module.

As for the randomness, did you try putting `np.random.seed(seed)` at the beginning of your script? If you also use randomness from the python `random` module, then also do `random.seed(seed)`. With that, you shouldn't need the `self.seed` attribute of `Model`, just call the regular `np.random.choice` etc.

Comment: Exactly. I do not use the regular random model. import numpy is not the first thing to be imported. I import ``` import os
import sys

from joblib import Parallel, delayed

import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd``` and

Comment: And then import datetime
import json
import logging
import os
from math import ceil,

Comment: np.random.seed(seed) did not work. That's exactly the point.

Comment: Ah, when you use parallel processing (joblib) it's a very different discussion. Then the source of uncontrolled randomness is most likely the non-deterministic order in which the code is executed.

Comment: Actually I only use it when a run the sensitivity analysis. For the example, although I import it, I do not use it.

Comment: It's hard to say anything meaningful without a minimal working example.

Comment: It may be that some external package you use makes use of python's `random` module. You should probably seed that module even if you do not use it directly in your own code.

Comment: Thanks. @maarten I tried to replicate it. With None, the example did not replicate, but it did with 0. In my code, still did not work with 0. So, now I'm guessing it is not about anything I import...