# numpy.intersect1d does not work on dictionary.keys()

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, set

I tried to use numpy's `intersect1d` to compare the keys in two dictionaries. However, this always returns an intersection of zero, for some reason related to dictionary keys being objects. I want to know why this behavior is desireable in any way.

```
d1 = {'a':1, 'b':2}
d2 = {'b':2, 'c':3}
np.intersect1d(d1.keys(), d2.keys())
> array([], dtype=object)
```

However,

```
np.intersect1d(list(d1.keys()), list(d2.keys()))
> array(['b'], dtype='<U1')
```

Is this intended behavior and if so, why?

Comment: Dictionary keys indeed behave differently than a list. For instance you cannot slice them (`d1.keys()[0]`). Is there any reason to use numpy here and not a simple `set(d1)&set(d2)`?

Comment: Both `dn.keys()` and `set(dn.keys())` result in an empty array, and also trigger "unexpected type(s)" warning in PyCharm editor. It seems like `np.intersect1d()` does not support all iterable types in Python.

Comment: `intersect1d` sorts the inputs, sorts their combination and looks for duplicates.  There's no reason to expect it be faster than the hashing based `intersection` of python `set` operations.

Comment: The first thing `intersect1d` does is `np.asanyarray(...)` of its arguments.  You can see this by looking at the `[source]` link in the docs.  It is common practice in numpy functions.

Comment: @mozway Sometimes one wants to use numpy because set operations in python do not return a deterministic order and cannot be seeded due to python's hash seed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585108/disable-hash-randomization-from-within-python-program But yes, it's mostly a matter of convenience, as to avoid a `sorted(set() & set())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary keys are special objects (set-like) that are dynamic views on the dictionary's keys (see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views)). They do behave "unexpectedly" (for instance you can't slice them like a list: `d1.keys()[0]`)

Now I'm not sure *why* (see below) [`np.intersect1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) is not working as expected on `dict.keys()`, but why use numpy here anyway? This function is defined to work on arrays, not on any object.

Furthermore, since the objects would need to be converted to arrays, this is slower than pure python. Better use a simple [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) intersection `set(d1) & set(d2)`, or even better (as suggested by @nocomment): `d1.keys() & d2.keys()`:

```
d1 = dict.fromkeys(range(1, 1_000_000))
d2 = dict.fromkeys(range(1, 2_000_000, 2))

%timeit np.intersect1d(list(d1), list(d2))
# 433 ms ± 97.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit set(d1) & set(d2)
# 162 ms ± 19.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

% timeit d1.keys() & d2.keys()
# 60.8 ms ± 12.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

##### but *why*?

`intersect1d` takes two **array_like** as input, which are defined as any scalar or sequence than can be converted to array ([doc](https://numpy.org/devdocs/glossary.html#term-array_like)). However `np.array(d1.keys())` creates an object array containing the `keys` object (a single object) and not the keys as items:

```
np.array(d1.keys())
# array(dict_keys(['a', 'b']), dtype=object)

np.array(d1.keys()).size
# 1
```

A perhaps interesting demonstration is to see the effect of a self intersection, yielding this unique object:

```
np.intersect1d(d1.keys(), d1.keys())
# array([dict_keys(['a', 'b'])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: How fast is `d1.keys() & d2`?

Comment: @nocomment good idea, this is actually faster (NB. `d1.keys() & d2` and `d1.keys() & d2.keys()` are identical)

Answer (score 1):

Arguments of `intersect1d()` are

```
ar1, ar2array_like
    Input arrays. Will be flattened if not already 1D.
```

see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html.

Return values of `dict.keys()` are dictionary view *objects* , see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views. Hence, `numpy` converts these view objects into arrays of objects as they are not collections of numbers:

```
>>> np.array({'a':1, 'b':2}.keys())
array(dict_keys(['a', 'b']), dtype=object)
```

And now `intersect1d()` will fail as these input arrays each have just one element: `dict_keys(['a', 'b'])` in the first array and `dict_keys(['b', 'c'])` in the second array. These are different objects and hence their intersection is a void set.

Comment: How do you know it's just one element? I'd see it if it were `array([dict_keys(['a', 'b'])])`, but it isn't.

Comment: @nocomment `np.array(d1.keys()).size` -> `1` ; `np.array(list(d1)).size` -> `2`

Comment: @mozway Is that visible in what the answer shows? Does `array(x, dtype=object)` with `x` not surrounded with `[]` always mean it's a single element? (I have never had such a case.)

Comment: @nocomment. You have a scalar array there. That's a thing in numpy. The shape is `()`