# set has no order but random.choice( list(set) ) is unstable given random seed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found a weird result of this below code on my project (below code is equivalent to the code in my project since I have to remove parts that are irrelevant to the question):

```
import random
random.seed(9000)

...
list1 = [0, 1]
list2 = []
set_diff = set(list1) - set(list2)
print( set_diff )
list_diff = list( set_diff )
print( list_diff )
print( random.choice( list_diff ) )
```

The result is unstable since the order (as printed) of set_diff is unstable (set is supposed to have no order). Result could be:

```
{'0', '1'}
['0', '1']
1
```

or

```
{'1', '0'}
['1', '0']
0
```

in different runs.
Could anyone please explain why? Thanks!

Comment: The order of a set is non-deterministic, and cannot be fixed with a random seed...

Comment: ah, then list(set) will give stochastic output. Thanks a lot!

Comment: hashes and set's don't have an order.

Comment: Then what affects the result of print( set ) and list( set )? Why they're different between runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set is unordered and so will yield its elements in any order. However, this order is consistent within one python invocation. That is, `set_ = set(range(N)); list(set_) == list(set_)` is always true within in the same python program. Python 3.2+ explicitly makes sure that the ordering will inconsistent from one python instance to the next (this is a security consideration relating to denial of service attacks involving dictionary construction). This is the behaviour you are seeing.

To avoid this you need to set the environment variable [`PYTHONHASHSEED`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) to the same value before you start your program. This is in addition to setting the random seed before using `random.choice`.

```
export PYTHONHASHSEED=1
python myscript.py
```

A simpler solution, however, is to create a sorted list before doing `random.choice`. ie.

```
random.choice(sorted({1, 2, 3}))
```