# How is the order of elements returned by list(frozenset()) determined?

Tags: python, list, set, frozenset

I have a following exemplary setup in Python:

```
a = list(frozenset(['haha', 'lol']))
b = list(frozenset(['lol', 'haha']))
```

Does

`a == b`

always return *True*?

Is it possible that the *list* of *frozenset* of the same elements can return *False* with the above setup?

Comment: I was going to post an answer to this question, but since it's been (rightfully) closed, I've posted my answer to the dupe target [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51578541/4014959). It adds a little info about the "interesting" hashing behaviour of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalence semantics between (frozen)sets are that if they contain equivalent items they are equivalent. Sets do not have order.

But, since lists **have** order, the cast to list can potentially cause them to not be equivalent (depends on the order of iteration over the (frozen)set - which is an implementation detail).

Here is an example of a collision in the internal implementation that causes a different iteration order due to the instertion order (this is in CPython implementation):

```
>>> a = list(frozenset([1, 9]))
>>> b = list(frozenset([9, 1]))
>>> a == b
False
```

Example with strings:

First we need to find a collision (I will not go into details):

```
>>> hash('1') % 8
0
>>> hash('2') % 8
5
>>> hash('3') % 8
2
>>> hash('4') % 8
3
>>> hash('5') % 8
1
>>> hash('6') % 8
4
>>> hash('7') % 8 
5  # same as '2' ! Found!
```

Now we need to add in different order to the set to cause a re-hash (again, not going into details):

```
>>> s1, s2 = '2', '7'
>>> a = list(frozenset([s1, s2]))
>>> b = list(frozenset([s2, s1]))
>>> a == b
False
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. It might be a coincidence, but I just couldn't reproduce the same thing with strings. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @Michal I've updated my answer. You just need to find a collision in the internal set hash.